# Sticky menu bar "jumps"/flicker while scrolling in Safari

Tags: jquery, menubar, sticky

I have a problem with my sticky menu-bar that seems to jump/flicker while scrolling in Safari. 
I've googled arround but it seems very complex to me, so maybe you can help me out?

The website is: http://12hrs.net

My Jquery looks like this:

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
$(".full-header").sticky({
    topSpacing: 0,
    wrapperClassName: 'full-header'
});


$('.image-wrapper').hover(function(){


    $(this).find('.mouse-effect').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.6'});
    $(this).find('.extra-links').stop().animate({'top':'64%'});

},function(){


    $(this).find('.mouse-effect').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'});
    $(this).find('.extra-links').stop().animate({'top':'-64%'});

});
$("li[data-id='id-166'] a.go-link").remove();

$(".gallery-option a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var view = $(this).attr("id");
    if (view == "three") {
        $(".holder li").removeClass("four columns").addClass("one-third column");
        if ($data) {
            $("ul.holder").removeAttr("style");
            $data.find("li").removeClass("four columns").addClass("one-third column")
        }
    } else {
        $(".holder li").removeClass("one-third column").addClass("four columns");
        if ($data) {
            $("ul.holder").removeAttr("style");
            $data.find("li").removeClass("one-third column").addClass("four columns")

        }
    }
});

$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

$(".ads img").addClass("img-frame");

$('#main-menu li a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

        var content = $(this).attr('href');
        var checkURL = content.match(/^#([^\/]+)$/i);
        if(checkURL){

            var goPosition = $(content).offset().top - 80;
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: goPosition}, 'slow');

        }else{
            window.location = content;
        }

});

$("#main-menu li").click(function () {
    $("#main-menu li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active")
});

$(".filter li a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var test = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $(".filter li a").removeClass("main-btn").addClass("gray");
    $(this).removeClass("gray").addClass("main-btn");
});

$("#foot a").click(function () {
    $("#menu li").removeClass("active");
    $("#menu li:first").addClass("active")
});

var $filterType = $("#filterOptions li.active a").attr("rel");
var $holder = $("ul.holder");
var $data = $holder.clone();
$("#filterOptions li a").click(function (e) {
    $("#filterOptions li").removeClass("active");
    var $filterType = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    if ($filterType == "all") var $filteredData = $data.find("li");
    else var $filteredData = $data.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterType + "]");
    $holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
        duration: 800,
        easing: "easeInOutQuad"
    }, function () {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
         $('.image-wrapper').hover(function(){

            $(this).find('.mouse-effect').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.6'});
            $(this).find('.extra-links').stop().animate({'top':'64%'});

            },function(){


            $(this).find('.mouse-effect').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'});
            $(this).find('.extra-links').stop().animate({'top':'-64%'});

            });
    });
    return false;
});
var lastId, topMenu = $("#main-menu"),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 500;
menuItems = topMenu.find('a');

    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function () {

        content = $(this).attr("href");
        var checkURL = content.match(/^#([^\/]+)$/i);

        if(checkURL){

            var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
            if (item.length) return item

        }
    });
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function () {
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop) return this
    });
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
    if (lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id;
       menuItems.parent().removeClass("active").end().filter("[href=#" + id + "]").parent().addClass("active")
    }
});
```

});

jQuery(window).load(function () {

```
 jQuery(".mainSlider").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: true
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually fix this by removing the `z-index` line for your class `.full-header` in your `layout.css`

Comment: awesome!! Who would have thought it was that easy?!

Comment: haha the joys of css, no worries glad I could help. I like the design of your site by the way!

Comment: thanks man! I'm still working on it, but it slowly takes form!